# Match with regex any string except a string provided

Tags: regex

In order to configure apache I am strugelling with one regex. My goal is to match any string, but a provided string. I know this has been asked a couple of times on stackoverflow, however I could not fix it so far.

The regex should match

```
/home/www/dir1/*
/home/www/dir_wl/example1/*
/home/www/dir_wl/example2/*
```

It should not match

```
/home/www/dir1/MEW/*
/home/www/dir_wl/example1/MEW/*
/home/www/dir_wl/example2/MEW*
```

Here is the entire line:
    `<Directory ~ "^/home/www/(dir1|dir_wl/.*(?!MEW))/(?!MEW/)">`

Any help is greatly apreciated!

Comment: `/home/www/(?!.*\bMEW\b).*` or `/home/www/(?!.*/MEW/).*`

Answer (score 0):

I got it with "grep -P".  "-P" means "[Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html)".  The program you are working with must support this.

I created the file "dirs.txt" with the following content:

```
/home/www/dir1/*
/home/www/dir_wl/example1/*
/home/www/dir_wl/example2/*

/home/www/dir1/MEW/*
/home/www/dir_wl/example1/MEW/*
/home/www/dir_wl/example2/MEW*
```

Then I run this command.

```
cat dirs.txt | grep -P "^/home/www/(dir1|dir_wl)/(?!MEW)(((?!/MEW).)*$)"
```

It returns ...

```
/home/www/dir1/*
/home/www/dir_wl/example1/*
/home/www/dir_wl/example2/*
```

This does the same on a much more simple way ...

```
cat regex.txt | grep -E "^/home/www/(dir1|dir_wl)/" | grep -v -E "/MEW"
```